# Creating a new document in SharePoint, opened the new document in the App by default. Why has this suddenly stopped working?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

Sometime in January 2024, I was excited to learn that I could setup a Document Library in SharePoint Online, and have the new document open directly in the installed Microsoft application when clicking the "New" button (for example, a Word document would open in the Microsoft Word application, and NOT Word Online):

[image]

I've revisited the application today, and noticed this no longer works - when clicking on New, the document is always opened in Word Online.  I've checked the document library settings, and can confirm that the default open behavior for browser-enabled documents is 'Open in the client application':

[image]

Is there another setting that I should be looking for?  Is it possible my tenant was just being tested for this feature, before it was rolled back recently?  I would really like to have this feature back - and no, I was not imagining that it worked in January, I performed client demonstrations and built a solution around it :)